# How many IO pins in C8051F975

Tags: microcontroller

I can't tell how many IO pins that are available on the C8051F975.
SiLabs website, Farnell and the datasheet p. 42 says 19 IO pins, so I guess that is correct, but the according to the datasheet p. 38 there is 21 IO pins.

[C8051F975 datasheet](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F97x.pdf)

I'm trying to use this MCU in a schematic, but I cannot get it finished before I know which of the pins are actually available.

Comment: The datasheet has your answer.

Comment: Please point to the answer then.

Comment: It depends which package you plan to use.

Comment: The C8051F975 only comes in QFN-24

Comment: I would say it is an error, because there are 19 analog inputs (as the table on page 42 says) but 21 digital I/Os. Also another error is the numbering in table on pages 39-40.

Comment: I agree, those numbers in the table does not belong to the QFN-24 package.
But which IO's are actually on the QFN-24 package?
I think that there must be two pins which are not IO's, but I cannot find anywhere which pins.

Comment: In fact there are 18 analog inputs. It looks like they just duplicated columns in table 4.1 and forgot to fill in the correct numbers, because for other packages there are also always 3 digital pins which are not analog pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this from SiLabs Support:

> The package figure (Figure 3.3) is correct. There are 19 full-featured GPIO, since P6.0 and P6.1 don’t have a full-fledged output mode (no push-pull output). They also can’t be used for any analog peripherals. They can be used as open-drain inputs and outputs, though.
>   I've put the issue into our system to get fixed. Thank you for letting us know!

Answer (score 0):

There are 24 pins (+ GND pad) on the QFN-24 package on page 38.

2 pins are VDD and GND -> 22pins.
1 pin is RST/C2CK -> 21.

If you want to use a hardware debugger, then do not use
1 pin P5.2/C2D as an I/O -> **20 I/O pins**.